# How to split a string from first HashTable and store it to a second HashTable?

Tags: c#, hashtable

I have a string which I separate with '*' and then store it to a `Hashtable` ht1.

```
String fString = "DAVCFW_ACK*DAVCFW_20_30_90*DAVCFW_15.5_20.1_35.0*DAVCFW_40_230_110*DAVCFW_END";
string[] words = fString.Split('*');
int i = 0;
Hashtable ht1 = new Hashtable();
foreach(string s in words) {
    ht1.Add(i,s);
    i++;
}
```

Then I remove some characters from it and store it to another `Hashtable`, ht2

```
Hashtable ht2 = new Hashtable();
int j = 0;
for (int t = 0; t < ht1.Count; t++)
{
    String str = ht1[t].ToString();
    string str2 = str.Substring(7);
    Console.WriteLine("str2:" + str2);
    ht2.Add(j, str2);
    j++;
}
int count = ht2.Count;
ht2.Remove(0);
ht2.Remove(count-1);
```

And the results are like this:

> 20_30_90
>
> 15.5_20.1_35.0
>
> 40_230_110

But I need to store only numbers in the `Hashtable`. Like this:

> k=1 | 20.0 | 30.0 | 90.0
>
> k=2 | 15.5 | 20.1 | 35.0
>
> k=3 | 40.0 | 230.0 |110.0

What do I have to do? I try to use split with '_' but it doesn't work, maybe my syntax is wrong?

Comment: `string[] numbers = "40_230_110".Split('_')` should work fine

Comment: And how about store it into Hash again? I am so confuse. :(

Answer (score 1):

This could work as well:

```
String fString = "DAVCFW_ACK*DAVCFW_20_30_90*DAVCFW_15.5_20.1_35.0*DAVCFW_40_230_110*DAVCFW_END";

var items = fString.Split('*');
var values = items.ToList().Select(s => s.Substring(7).Split('_'));
var hash = new Hashtable();
var i=0;
values.ToList().ForEach(v => hash.Add(++i, String.Join("|", v)));
```

and the Dump output (from LinqPad) is:

```
Key Value 
5 END 
4 40|230|110 
3 15.5|20.1|35.0 
2 20|30|90 
1 ACK
```

EDIT

... and print the values to console as

```
foreach (var key in hash.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, hash[key]);
}
```

Comment: I ran it and i got result like System.Collections.DictionaryEntry

Comment: Ran where? Visual studio, LinqPad?

Comment: I run on visual studio

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. In the above code, `hash` variable is of type `System.Collections.Hashtable` and the value is a string, i.e. `hash[1].GetType()` is of type `System.String`. Where are you getting `DictionaryEntry` ?

Comment: I copy your code and put console.writeline(hash); and then the result is System.Collections.DictionaryEntry. Why it cant show the value like your?

Comment: There is no way the above code can print `DictionaryEntry` when running `Console.WriteLine(hash);` the output must `System.Collections.Hashtable`. See above edit for how to print the values.

Comment: wow it works. I shouldn't put consolt.WriteLine(hash). I am so confuse about syntax of c#. Thanks sir. :D

Comment: One more question. I need to remove first and last line. What i have to do? I try to write code like hash.remove("END"); and hash.remove("ACK"); but It doesn't work.

Comment: `hash.remove` wants a key, not the value. So in your case it'd `hash.remove(1)` since the value for '1' is "ACK". Alternatively, you can modify the code that adds to the hash and exclude "ACK"/"END" strings.

Comment: yes, I use `hash.remove(1);` to remove ACK. but I can't use `hash.remove(hash[hash.Count]);` to remove END. Am I wrong on syntax?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Split('_')` should be ok.

Another way could be to use regular expressions:

```
for(int cnt = 1 ....) {
    Regex rex = new Regex(@"\d+(\.\d+)?");
    MatchCollection mac = rex.Matches("your string of numbers");


    string string4Hash = string.Format("{0}", cnt);
    foreach (Match match in mac)
    {
        string4Hash = string.Format("{0}|{1}", string4Hash, double.Parse(match.Value));
    }  
}
```

Comment: I ran it and i got result like
System.Collections.DictionaryEntry

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a lot less complicated by not storing intermediate results in hashtables, there is no need for doing that. Furthermore, I would suggest using type-safe collections and Linq really helps here. So I would suggest this code:

```
String fString = "DAVCFW_ACK*DAVCFW_20_30_90*DAVCFW_15.5_20.1_35.0*DAVCFW_40_230_110*DAVCFW_END";
var words = fString.Split('*');
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<double>>();
for (int i = 1; i != words.Length - 1; i++) {
    var numbers = words[i].Split('_')
                          .Skip(1)
                          .Select(n => Double.Parse(n))
                          .ToList();
    dictionary.Add(i, numbers);
}
```

Testing it:

```
foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys) {
    Console.WriteLine(key);
    foreach (double number in dictionary[key]) {
        Console.WriteLine(" " + number);
    }
}
```

yields the correct results:

- 1
- 20
- 30
- 90
- 2
- 155
- 201
- 350
- 3
- 40
- 230
- 110